# How to detect if there is some fire wall or other causes which prevent me to connect to a specific server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, networking, request

If my web application has a specific component(widget) which make a connection to another server(which is out of control) to read from an `xml file` .

sometimes the admin of the server which i connect to put a firewall or change some configuration . and when my application try to connect to this server it takes long time before the widget comes empty.

The problem is the time trying to connect to that server is a part of the time to load the page . and i feel there 's some thing wrong with all this time to request the page !

---

How can i determine if i can connect to that server to read the data or there is some issue which prevent me to do this.?

Comment: @Aristos: If the firewall is configured to silently drop packages to blocked servers or ports, then you don't immediately get an error. Instead, it'll take some time until the time-out expires and the senders assumes that it won't get an answer.

Comment: @just_name: What sort of "widget" is it? Is it HTML, ActiveX, Flash?

Comment: it's HTML widget .

`it'll take some time until the time-out expires`.yeah this is the problem ,i feel like the whole page load takes time more than usual and when i stop the connection to this server the page loads so quickly .

Comment: To check for issues with the remote server use command tools like ping and telnet. Are you able to telnet to the port on which your app tries to connect? If ping is not possible you can write a test program in C# using System.Net.Socket object. If socket connects to the port without errors, its working fine. You can increase the frequency of this program to check if packets are silently dropped.

Comment: I know that there's some problem with the remote server , and i can't connect, and i will call the admin to fix it. but this sever is out of my control so i wanna to isolate it so the page load quickly even this widget can't connect to the server

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what your widget is composed of and thus why it blocks the loading of the page. But two ways to decouple the widget for the page loading are:

1. Put the widget in an *iframe* element.
2. First insert a placeholder for the widget (e.g. a *div* element and a *Loading...* text). Then, after the page has loaded, use Javascript to replace the placeholder with the effective HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowed to use this XML feed on your site? If not, they may be deliberately blocking your access to it.

However, I would cache the XML file locally, and let a cron job regularly pull the newest version from the other server.

Comment: could u explain how to cache the `xml file`. i need some explanation to the last line please